# A terminal open everytime when I open Chrome or visual studio code

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, terminal

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQR1y.jpg)

A terminal open everytime when I open Chrome or visual studio code. It started to do do this when I'm started coding in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. You need to do

`npm uninstall typescript --g`